# Open a text file, scan it and plot it in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, import

I am trying to open a text file in MATLAB and plot it in a graph. The following is my code:

```
%% Get the data 
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*txt', 'Pick text file');
x=filename(:,1);
y=filename(:,2);
plot(x,y);
```

But each time I run it, I get following error:

```
Error using plot
Invalid first data argument.
Error in readtxtfile (line 5)
plot(x,y);
```

The text file that I imported has 2 rows. I am planning to plot the first row with the second say plot (row 1, row 2) in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the name of the file stored in `filename` combined with the path to the directory where the file is stored in `pathname` but you actually haven't read any of the contents.  To do that, the easiest thing would be to use [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).  I'm assuming your text file is properly formatted to have two rows of data as you stated.  If this is the case, you need to change the way you're indexing into your data.  You have it indexing entire columns instead of rows so you need to flip the indexing in your code.  Also, you need a call to `dlmread`, then access the columns of the resulting matrix:

```
%% Get the data 
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*txt', 'Pick text file');
data = dlmread(fullfile(pathname, filename));
x=data(1,:);
y=data(2,:);
plot(x,y);
```

Notice that I made the full path to your file to use [`fullfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) because using `uigetfile` allows you to read in a file from anywhere on your computer so we make sure that we capture the full path to your file.   Again to reiterate, `pathname` is the directory of where the file is contained and `filename` is the name of the file contained in the directory.

Comment: this code works I was able to plot it together... but what I got was just a straight line plot which I was not looking for I am not sure how that happened I feel it didn't read the values in the txt file

Comment: it worked now by the following modifications
`x=data(:,1);`
`y=data(:,2);`

Comment: You said your text file had two ROWS, not COLUMNS. in the future, make sure you know what their differences are. That's why I changed the code to be so compared to your original.